# c# chat application. Can't display all logged in user's names

Tags: c#

this C# code represents a ViewModel for a WPF login screen. It incorporates fields for user information and server connection, a collection to store users, and commands for login and window closure. The constructor initializes these elements, including a command (CombinedCommand) that executes login-related functions. The UserName property facilitates interaction with the user's name, updating the UI through OnPropertyChanged. The LoggedIN method opens a new main window upon successful login. Overall, this ViewModel encapsulates the logic and properties needed for handling user authentication in a Windows Presentation Foundation application.

```
public class LoginVM : viewModelBase
{
    private readonly User user;
    private Server _server;
  
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get;}
    public ICommand CombinedCommand { get; }
    public ICommand CloseLoginWindowCommand { get; }
    
    public LoginVM()
    {
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        user = new User();
        _server = new Server();
       _server.connectedEvent += Userconnected;
        
        CombinedCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            LoggedIN(o);
            _server.ConnectToServer(UserName);
            CloseLoginWindow();

        }, o =>  canExecuteCommands(o));
    }

    private void Userconnected()
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            Name = _server._packetReader.ReadMessage(),
        };
        if (!Users.Any(x => x.Name == user.Name))
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {Users.Add(user);});
        }
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get => user.Name;
        set
        {
            user.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserName));
        }
    }

    public void LoggedIN(object Parameter)
    {
       MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
       mainWindow.DataContext = this;
       mainWindow.Show();
    }
    
   private bool canExecuteCommands(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is string userName)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void CloseLoginWindow()
    {
        Window window = Application.Current.Windows[0];
        window.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is a code snippet of the class loginViewModel. I also have a another viewModel mainViewModel. so after the user logs in I want to display all their names in a listView, what is the optimal way to do it.

Comment: BTW, your `public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }` property should be `{ get; }`-only - this is because `ObservableCollection<T>` properties must be readonly so the collection object reference can't be replaced (which breaks everything). The same applies to all collection properties in general, really.

Comment: Please format your code so that it will be more compact.